# Copying a file to same folder or same directory in MS Word

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

Following coding is used for copying a word document from one folder to another folder, where the path is defined.

```
Sub copyfile()
   Const SourceFile = "D:\Macrotest\B\xxxxxxxxx_queries.docx"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
        If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
        'Check to see if the file is read-only
        If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then
            'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "D:\Macrotest\A\", True
        Else
            'The file exists and is read-only.
            'Remove the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
            'Replace the file
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "D:\Macrotest\A\", True
            'Reapply the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
        End If
    Else
        'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "D:\Macrotest\A\", True
    End If
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

I need a code that moves a file from a folder to the **same folder** where I am accessing. I have used `\` instead of `D:\Macrotest\A\` following message pops up. Error shows in `fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "\", True` above last `End If`

```
Sub copyfile()
    Const SourceFile = "D:\Macrotest\B\xxxxxxxxx_queries.docx"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
    If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
        'Check to see if the file is read-only
        If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then
            'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "\", True
        Else
            'The file exists and is read-only.
            'Remove the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
            'Replace the file
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "\", True
            'Reapply the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
        End If
    Else
        'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "\", True
    End If
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why would you post a screenshot of your code? What's the point? Downvoted until you fix your question.

Comment: That's better, downvote removed.

Comment: "now upvote it" uh-huh, yeah well, that's not how it works. And why are you using block quotes for everything? Which line throws the error exactly? Can you copy the actual error into the post? A screenshot is nice *as a complement*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug `fso.copyfile SourceFile, "\", True`  above last  `end if` is where error is showing

Comment: `"\"` is the root directory of the current drive (most likely ``C:\`` where you don't have write access). What exactly do you mean by *"moves a file from a folder to the same folder where I am accessing"*? Moving a file onto itself doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers A copy of file from `D:\Macrotest\B\xxxxxxxxx_queries.docx` should come to the folder from wherever I am using whether it is `C:\ARYF` or `D:\dummy`.

Answer (score 0):

"\" is the root directory of the current drive (most likely `C:\`). You don't seem to have write access there, so that's where your error is coming from.

To copy the file to your current working directory use `.\` (`.` is the path notation for the current directory).

```
fso.CopyFile SourceFile, ".\", True
```

Comment: There is no pop up or error, but file is not there in the current drive or folder.

Comment: It worked fine when I tested it. Check that the current working directory is what you think it is: `WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory`